# How to add a input text box for each bar in a bar graph using html, javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I want to create a bar graph like below:

[image: Bar Graph]
Right now I have created the following graph:

[image]
Please find my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.x-axis path {
    stroke:white;
    fill:none;
}
.x-axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
    stroke-opacity:.8;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bars rect {
    fill:steelblue;
    fill-opacity:.9;
}
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#precise-value {
    fill:white;
    font-size: 12px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


(function(){

    var margin = {top: 50, bottom: 50, left:250, right: 40};
    var width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], 1.8,0);

    var numTicks = 5;
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
                    .orient("top")
                    .tickSize((-height))
                    .ticks(numTicks);
 
  
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width+margin.left+margin.right)
                .attr("height", height+margin.top+margin.bottom)
                .attr("class", "base-svg");
 
    var barSvg = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")")
                .attr("class", "bar-svg");
 
    var x = barSvg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x-axis");

 
 
 
  
    d3.csv("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Graph/sampledata.csv", function(error, data) {

        var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Count; } );
        var xMin = 0;
        xScale.domain([xMin, xMax]);
        yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Symptom_Category; }));

        d3.select(".base-svg").append("text")
            .attr("x", margin.left)
            .attr("y", (margin.top)/2)
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .text("Symptom Pareto")
            .attr("class", "title");

        var groups = barSvg.append("g").attr("class", "labels")
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g");

        groups.append("text")
                .attr("x", "0")
                .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.Symptom_Category); })
                .text(function(d) { return d.Symptom_Category; })
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dy", ".9em")
                .attr("dx", "-.32em")
                .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "label"+i; });

        var bars = groups
                    .attr("class", "bars")
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.Count); })
                    .attr("height", height/20)
                    .attr("x", xScale(xMin))
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.Symptom_Category); })
                    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "bar"+i; });

        groups.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.Count); })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.Symptom_Category); })
                .text(function(d) { return d.Count; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dy", "1.2em")
                .attr("dx", "-.32em")
                .attr("id", "precise-value");
  
        bars
            .on("mouseover", function() {`enter code here`
                var currentGroup = d3.select(this.parentNode);
                currentGroup.select("rect").style("fill", "brown");
                currentGroup.select("text").style("font-weight", "bold");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                var currentGroup = d3.select(this.parentNode);
                currentGroup.select("rect").style("fill", "steelblue");
                currentGroup.select("text").style("font-weight", "normal");
            });
   
        x.call(xAxis);
        var grid = xScale.ticks(numTicks);
        barSvg.append("g").attr("class", "grid")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(grid, function(d) { return d; })
            .enter().append("line")
                .attr("y1", 0)
                .attr("y2", height+margin.bottom)
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d); })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d); })
                .attr("stroke", "white");

    });

})();

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

How will I add right side text boxes in my current graph?
I am new in learning javascript. Kindly help me in solving the problem. I know this can be done by svg d3 but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: you can draw your grid with an additional xAxis with negative tick mark length

Comment: have you written any code to create the boxes on the right hand side?

Comment: @ialarmedalien No I have not yet written the code for boxes as I am not able to understand how to write it. Could you please help me?

Comment: @rioV8 How to do that. Could you please explain?

Comment: Can anyone suggest me what to do?